# how to assign set<> iterator to pointer c++

Tags: c++, stl, set

I need to assign set<> iterator to pointer, while I pass set as argument `void ProcessVessel(ContainerTerminal* containerTerminal, set<ArrivedVessel> * arrivedVesselPool)` whereas 
 `ArrivedVessel` is a class and after that I made iterator `std::set<ArrivedVessel>::iterator it;` for loop and I made for loop `for (it = arrivedVesselPool->begin(); it != arrivedVesselPool->end(); it++)`, till now compiler doesn't show me any error but when I assign `it` to the pointer which is `Vessel* currentVessel` like this `currentVessel = &(*it);`, compiler gives error

> A value of type 'const ArrivedVessel*' cannot be assigned to an entity of type 'vessel*'.

However for converting iterator I found it on this link [iterator to pointer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743055/convert-iterator-to-pointer) but I couldn't understand it perfectly.

Here is the piece of source code

```
void ProcessVessel(set<ArrivedVessel> * arrivedVesselPool) {
        std::set<ArrivedVessel>::iterator it;
        for (it = arrivedVesselPool->begin(); it != arrivedVesselPool->end(); it++)
        {
            Vessel* currentVessel;
            currentVessel = &(*it);}
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sidenote: You forgot to check that `arrivedVesselPool` is not `nullptr`. Perhaps it'd be better to take the argument by reference? `set<ArrivedVessel>& arrivedVesselPool`

Comment: @rafix07 I tried it already sir but it doesn't work.

Comment: Create a [mre] please.

Comment: "doesen't work" is not an error description. Show exactly what you tried, what you want to achieve and what the result is instead.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (with `const` and some syntax corrections): https://godbolt.org/z/ybHPMb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::set` doesn't allow you to modify the objects stored within it so its iterators return `const` references. You can only therefore assign to a `const` pointer:

```
void ProcessVessel(set<ArrivedVessel> * arrivedVesselPool) {
    std::set<ArrivedVessel>::iterator it;
    for (it = arrivedVesselPool->begin(); it != arrivedVesselPool->end(); it++)
    {
        const ArrivedVessel* currentVessel;
        currentVessel = &(*it);
    }
```

If you want to modify the elements you need to use a different container. For example you could use `std::vector`, you would have to take care of making sure elements are unique yourself. You'd also need to make sure that the items remain unique after they have been modified.

Comment: `const Vessel* currentVessel;` should likely be `const ArrivedVessel* currentVessel;` (unless `ArrivedVessel` is inherited from `Vessel`).

Comment: Yes, in this way it is working  but I want to use `curentVessel` as a non-const pointer so I can pass it to other functions as well. In this way I can not use it to pass to the functions. for example **ct->AssignBerth(*currentVessel)** it shows `qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "vessel&" to initializer of type "const vessel" `

Comment: You can't modify the elements of a `std::set`, if you want to modify the elements use a different container

Comment: @AlanBirtles sir could you please give me example, how I can handle this all in same function.

Comment: I've added some more comments. Difficult to provide much more detail without knowing what you are trying to do

Comment: You could also extract the `ArrivedVessel` from the `set`, pass it to the functions that needs to modify it and then reinsert it in the `set`.

Comment: I tried it by using const_cast `step 1 ->` `const Vessel& cv =*it;` and `step 2->`   `Vessel& currentVessel = const_cast<Vessel&>(cv);`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I tried it by using const_cast `step 1 -> const Vessel& cv =*it;` and `step 2->` `Vessel& currentVessel = const_cast<Vessel&>(cv);`

Comment: `const_cast` will fix the compile error but you'll get undefined behaviour if you make modifications to the objects which would change their ordering in the `std::set`